# Create a form-data object in php back end

Tags: php, api, backend, form-data

I have to send files from my php back end to an API as form-data objects. These files were created directly in the back end and the sending is not associated with any HTML form.

The API documentation provides an example of sending a form-data object but in python, here it is:

```
files=[
  ('file',('owl-50267_1920.jpg',open('dataset/img/owl-1.jpg','rb')))
]
```

How can I do the same thing in php ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to create a [form-data object](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.curlfile.php) in PHP:

```php
$file = ['file' => new CURLFILE('path/to/file.ext')];
```

Example of usage:

```php
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, [
  CURLOPT_URL => 'API endpoint URL',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => ['file' => new CURLFILE('path/to/file.ext')],
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => ['X-API-KEY': 'api key']
]);

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

=> See previous answer here: [Send file using multipart/form-data request in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17862004/send-file-using-multipart-form-data-request-in-php)