# cURL failed: no post FIELDS sent

Tags: php, api, curl

I need to create a php curl request to an electronic signature service, sending a pdf file to be signed + a json payload.
When I simulate the api through postman, it works through the local / desktop app (so it's not a mistake on my partner side), but not from the web interface (error 415), because Content-type multipart/form is not sent for a reasin I can't explain.

Back to my php curl code, I have the same 415 error.
I tried to add infos in the output to better understand, but I can't figure out why and where there is a problem.
I have no worries for the auth request before to get the token, so technically speaking, it should be ok.

Any idea from someone?
Thanks a lot!

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://simply-cosi.luxtrust.com/api/sessions/create-generic/v1');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
// Crée un objet CURLFile
$cfile = curl_file_create('https://completelinktomyfileonline','application/pdf','20200929-PDF_Sign.pdf');


$post = array(
    'sessionPayload' => '\"{\"templateId\": 69920,\"labels\": [{\"lang\": \"FR\",\"value\": \"Signature_1\"},{\"lang\": \"EN\",\"value\": \"Signature_1\"}],\"steps\": [{\"templateStepName\": \"Signature\",\"labels\": [],\"documents\": [{\"name\": \"20200929-PDF_Sign.pdf\",\"sprofileCode\": \"BULK_PADES_SEAL_EMAIL\",\"isAnnex\": false}],\"signers\": [{\"userIdentifier\": {\"id\": 28148}}],\"watchers\": [],\"managers\": [],\"documentPlaceholders\": [{\"documentName\": \"20200929-PDF_Sign.pdf\",\"userIdentifier\": {\"id\": 28148},\"name\": \"Signer1\"}]}],\"start\":true}\";type=application/json',
'files' => $cfile
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
$headers = array(   "Content-Type: multipart/form-data", 
                    "Accept: application/json",
                     "Authorization: Bearer " . $token);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
print_r($info);
echo 'HTTP code: ' . $httpcode;
echo 'Result:' . $result;

if($result) print_r($post);
else echo "cURL failed: no POST fields sent";

if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
```

I think there's a problem in the syntax of $post in order to post FILE + JSON all together, but already tried many things with no success.
for instance: fopen, new CURLFILE, etc.

Comment: This might well help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/45847575/2310830

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, I still have the same 415 message error... but for sure that code is more customizable